# Pandas - Dump dataframe columns into dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want to dump a two-columns dataframe into a dictionary like this:

**My dataframe:**

```
df['col1'] = pd.Series(['id_1','id_2','id_3','id_4'])
df['col2'] = pd.Series(['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4'])
```

**Desired dictionary**

```
dict = {'id_1':'Name1','id_2':'Name2','id_3':'Name3',...}
```

What would be a nice way of doing this without looping through the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is calling `dict` directly on numpy array of `df`.

If your `df` has exact 2 columns:

```
dict(df.values)
```

If your `df` has more than 2 columns, just slicing 2 columns you want to convert and call `dict` on them:

```
dict(df[['col1', 'col2']].values)
```

Output:

```
{'id_1': 'Name1', 'id_2': 'Name2', 'id_3': 'Name3', 'id_4': 'Name4'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`df.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to set the dictionary keys and take only the column you want as values and call [`series.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) on it:

```
my_dict=df.set_index('col1')['col2'].to_dict()
```

Or you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to `zip` 2 columns and call the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-dict) function on it.

```
my_dict=dict(zip(df.col1,df.col2))
```

---

**Output:**

```
{'id_1': 'Name1', 'id_2': 'Name2', 'id_3': 'Name3', 'id_4': 'Name4'}
```

**P.S** *Don't use `dict` as a dictionary name since it is a python builtin func.*